# How to disable pressure sensitivity in com.github.gcacace:signature-pad

Tags: signaturepad

github.gcacace:signature-pad:1.3.1 it's working well but the signature line is thicker at the beginning and at some points i don't know how to disable the pressure sensitive so that the the whole signature has the same thickness.
I need your help please.

```
<com.github.gcacace.signaturepad.views.SignaturePad
 android:id="@+id/signature_pad"
 android:layout_width="420dp"
 android:layout_height="150dp"
 android:layout_gravity="center"
 app:penColor="@android:color/black"
 android:background="@drawable/signature_background"
 app:velocityFilterWeight="0.9"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally find out setting the `velocityFilterWeight` to 0.0 fix my issue.

```
<com.github.gcacace.signaturepad.views.SignaturePad
  android:id="@+id/signature_pad"
  android:layout_width="420dp"
  android:layout_height="150dp"
  android:layout_gravity="center"
  app:penColor="@android:color/black"
  android:background="@drawable/signature_background"
  app:velocityFilterWeight="0.0"
  app:penMinWidth="2dp"
  app:penMaxWidth="3dp"
/>
```